# What is wrong with Discogs and "Electronic" genre?

Tags: genre, genre-characteristics

I am using mp3tag to access Discogs database to clean up MP3 tags in my 4000+ items library. For insanely large number of results (1000-2000!) I am getting:

> Electronic

entry as the only or one of the genres.

I am getting this genre for artists like Michael Bolton, Britney Spears, Sandra and many, many more whose entire music is as far from "Electronic" as Mars from Earth.

Frankly saying, I could say that about 50% of my database (spanning over a really large variety of genres) had in the past received "Electronic" genere as one of the results. For even such surprising (?) creators like pure R&B artists or soft rock ballads authors.

Yes, that is truly around 50% of my database. I could risk the assumption that each one of two hits from mp3tag to Discogs database results in getting "Electronic" as one of the genre results.

What is this or what am I missing? Was there some kind of error, virus pollution or I don't know what of Discogs database some time ago? I mean, for the Got sake half of the world can't be composing and playing electronic music. This is rather a niche genere (especially these days), if I am not mistaken.

Comment: What does ‘electronic’ mean to _you_? There's a huge range of music styles created using software or hardware synths and/or electronic production techniques. People use the term to mean electronic dance music, electro, electronica, techo, grime, dubstep, big beat, synth-pop, trance, through to ‘EM’ (electronic music) in the vein of Jean-Michel Jarre and Tangerine Dream (where I believe the term was being used long before it got applied to those other genres).

Comment: Looking at your list of styles, I'd say that "electronic" means exactly the same to me as it does to you. Unfortunately (?) your list doesn't include styles like R&B, hip-hop, rap, reggae, pop, soul, funky, chill or even (!) opera for which I am also getting "electronic" as sole or one of the genres returned from Discogs. It doesn't matter what "electronic" means to me. The question is why Discogs is so insanely "polluted" with this genre? That it has it added even to those genres, artists and songs that are as far from "electronic" as Sun is from Pluto (examples given above).